# Visualising feature selection results for multiple classifiers and feature subset sizes

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib

I am using information gain feature selection technique to get different features subset sizes for my dataset, like so:

```py
fs1 = SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=10)
fs1.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train_fs1 = fs1.transform(X_train)
X_test_fs1 = fs1.transform(X_test)


fs2 = SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=20)
fs2.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train_fs2 = fs2.transform(X_train)
X_test_fs2 = fs2.transform(X_test)


fs3 = SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=30)
fs3.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train_fs3 = fs3.transform(X_train)
X_test_fs3 = fs3.transform(X_test)
```

I am then testing the performance of 4 different algorithms (Logistic Regression, SVM, AdaBoost and Decision Trees) using different subset sizes of feature selected features (subset 1 has k=10, so 10 features, subset 2 has 20 features, etc.). To evaluate the model's performance, I am calculating the Precision, Recall and AUC, like so:

```py
def compareAlgorithms(X_train, y_train, score):
    # Compare Algorithms
    seed = 7

    # prepare models
    models = []
    models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
    models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
    models.append(('Linear SVC', LinearSVC()))
    models.append(('ADABOOST', AdaBoostClassifier()))
    models.append(('DT', DecisionTreeClassifier()))


    # evaluate each model in turn
    results = []
    names = []
    scoring = score
    
    print(score, ":")
    
    for name, model in models:
        skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False, random_state=seed)
        #kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=seed)
        cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=skf, scoring=scoring)
        results.append(cv_results)
        names.append(name)
        msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
        print(msg)
        
    return results, names
```

As I now have lots of results, I am trying to plot the results to better visualise which algorithm is performing better with which subset. I want to create plots similar to the ones I found in [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11227-018-02738-w):

[image]

I have tried using matplotlib to do this, but have found it quite difficult seeing as I am trying to plot different classifiers on different features subset. I can (sort of) plot a line plot of the algorithms performance for one data subset using this function:

```py
def plot(results,names, score):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # plot for algorithm comparison
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(score)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.plot(results)
    ax.set_xticklabels(names)
    plt.show()
```

Which results in this plot:

[image]

The problem with the above plot (beside the overlapping model names below which I am working on fixing) is that it is for one feature subset.

Can anyone help me do a plot like the one in the paper I have attached and maybe direct me to useful resources for someone just starting to learn about data visualisation?

Many thanks.

Comment: What code have you already written to try and create the plots? It should be relatively easy to plot different data series for the different classifiers.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I have added some of the code I have written. Appreciate any help you can give as I'm very new to data visualisation using python :)

Comment: If I understand correctly the plot uses data for one feature subset (e.g. `k=10`). What do the multiple datapoints for the same algorithm represent?

Comment: Yes exactly, the 'results' variable contains the results for one of the subsets (e.g. k=10), for one score (e.g. precision). The multiple datapoints represent the results for the 5 different splits of the data in the cross validation. But I want to change this such that the x axis is the different data subsets and the y axis is the score value. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think the answer from @10xAI shows a good start. You should probably look into restructuring the data from a list of lists to a dictionary.

Comment: The current answers help but they do not answer my question regarding how to plot the results for different subsets of the data (as in the screenshot from the paper I have attached). Thanks anyway.

Comment: The fact that you want to plot different subsets does not change the code a lot, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggested answers, they helped. What I ended up doing is the following:

Firstly I changed my function that compares between the different models like so:

```py
def compareAlgorithmsFeatureSelection(X_train, y_train):
  
    # prepare configuration for cross validation test harness
    seed = 7

    # prepare models
    models = []
    models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
    models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
    models.append(('Linear SVC', LinearSVC()))
    models.append(('ADABOOST', AdaBoostClassifier()))
    models.append(('DT', DecisionTreeClassifier()))

    
    names = []
    precision_results=[]
    recall_results=[]
    auc_results=[]
    
    NumOfKFeatures=[10,20,30,40,50]
    
    for name, model in models:
        names.append(name)
        precision_model_results = []
        recall_model_results = []
        auc_model_results = []
    
        for x in NumOfKFeatures:
            # get X_train and X_test after applying FS
            fs = SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=x)
            fs.fit(X_train, y_train)
            X_train_fs = fs.transform(X_train)
            X_test_fs = fs.transform(X_test)

            # make splits for cross-validation
            skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False, random_state=seed)

            # calculate scores
            precision_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train_fs,
                                                                       y_train, cv=skf, scoring='precision')
            recall_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train_fs,
                                                                       y_train, cv=skf, scoring='recall')
            auc_cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X_train_fs,
                                                                       y_train, cv=skf, scoring='roc_auc')


            precision_model_results.append(precision_cv_results.mean()) 
            recall_model_results.append(recall_cv_results.mean())
            auc_model_results.append(auc_cv_results.mean())

        
        # append scores to final results list only after completed for an algorithm and all the feature subsets    
        precision_results.append(precision_model_results)
        print(precision_results)
        recall_results.append(recall_model_results)
        auc_results.append(auc_model_results)
        
        
    return precision_results, recall_results, auc_results, names
```

I then do the following to plot the score results for each feature subset using tips from answers provided by @Oxbowerce @10xAI and @Julio Jesus,:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")

subsets=[10,20,30,40,50]

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("Precision")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for x in range(len(subsets)):
    ax.plot(subsets, precision_results[x], label = names[x], marker = "o", linestyle = "--")
    
ax.set_ylabel("Precision")
ax.set_xlabel("Feature Selection Subsets")
ax.legend(loc = "best")
plt.show()
```

[image]

To plot recall and auc I just replace precision_results with the relevant results list.

Answer (score 1):

*You will have to study and understand Matplotlib and its tweaks.*

This code will do the basic work. You can extend it. Also, please go through the references that are added at the end.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'AUC':{'RF':[0.7,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.4], 'LR':[0.9,0.25,0.35,0.99,0.55], 'SVM':[0.3,0.5,0.8,0.6,0.7] } }
x = ['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5']

plt.plot(x, data['AUC']['RF'], marker='^', linestyle='solid') 
plt.plot(x,data['AUC']['LR'], marker='o', color='r',linestyle='dashed')  
plt.plot(x,data['AUC']['SVM'], marker='s', color='b',linestyle='dashdot')
```

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

**References** -

*[Matplotlib Official tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/index.html)

[Python Data Science Handbook by Jake VanderPlas](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.00-introduction-to-matplotlib.html)

[Matplotlib Lines](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D)

[Matplotlib Markers](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/markers_api.html)

[Matplotlib Colors](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/named_colors.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Try making these modifications to your function, it might look better.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# optional but I like this style
# plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")

def plot(results,names, score):
    # boxplot algorithm comparison
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(score)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(results, label = names, marker = "o", linestyle = "--")
    ax.set_ylabel(score)
    ax.legend(loc = "best")
    plt.show()
```

Here I'm not sure of the type of both `score` and `names`. But if both are strings it will work as I suggest

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Variable names contains a list of all the algorithm names that were used, I would need to iterate through the list to get a correct legend.

Answer (score 1):

If you restructure your data a bit it is relatively straight forward:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    "LR": [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.7],
    "SVM": [0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5],
    "Linear SVC": [0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6],
    "ADABOOST": [0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.7],
    "DT": [0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7]
}
subsets = [3, 5, 10, 20]

for model in data:
    plt.plot(subsets, data[model])
```

[image]

You can add a legend using `plt.legend`, axis titles can be set using `plt.xlabel`/`plt.ylabel`.